# Get the first day of the week for a Pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, series

I have the following df :

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

df = pd.DataFrame([
        ["A", "2018-08-03"],
        ["B", "2018-08-20"]
])
df.columns = ["Item", "Date"]
```

I want to get the first day of the week for every line of my df. I tried to do this :

```
df['Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df["Day_of_Week"] = df.Date.dt.weekday

df["First_day_of_the_week"] = df.Date - timedelta(days=df.Day_of_Week)
```

But I got that error message :

```
TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: Series
```

How can I get the first day of the week for a Series ?
My expected result is that :

- "A", "2018-08-03", "2018-07-30"
- "B", "2018-08-20", "2018-08-20"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately `timedelta` doesn't support a vectorized form so I would go for an `apply`

```
df["First_day_of_the_week"] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Date'] - timedelta(days=x['Day_of_Week']), axis=1)
```

**EDIT**

`timedelta` doesn't support vectorized arguments but can be multiplied by a vector :)

```
df["First_day_of_the_week"] = df.Date - df.Day_of_Week * timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: +! for the answer but`sunday` should be the first day right ?

Comment: That's right, I just re-produced the behavior of the original code. I guess is simply a matter of adding/substracting `1` from `df["Day_of_Week"] = df.Date.dt.weekday`

Comment: pandas assume monday is the first day of week?

Comment: yes, `datetime.date(2018,7,9).weekday()` returns `0`

Answer (score 20):

A vectorised solution is possible with NumPy:

```
df['First_day'] = df['Date'] - df['Date'].dt.weekday * np.timedelta64(1, 'D')

print(df)

  Item       Date  First_day
0    A 2018-08-03 2018-07-30
1    B 2018-08-20 2018-08-20
```

Comment: It's so fast! Thx

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution that doesn't require timedelta or lambda functions with subtractions:

```py
df['Date'].dt.to_period('W').dt.to_timestamp()
```

Answer (score 4):

Leave out your 'Day of week" calculation and do this.

```
df["First_day_of_the_week"] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: (x - timedelta(days=x.dayofweek)))
print(df)
```

giving

```
  Item       Date First_day_of_the_week
0    A 2018-08-03            2018-07-30
1    B 2018-08-20            2018-08-20
```

Comment: `weekday` and `dayofweek` are same ?

Comment: I meant he can leave out df["Day_of_Week"] = df.Date.dt.weekday

Comment: ya ok. `df.Date.dt.weekday` and `df.Date.dt.dayofweek` gives the same result, so both functions are same?

Answer (score 4):

You can stay in Pandas and use its [DateOffset](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects) objects:

```
>>> from pandas.tseries.offsets import Week

>>> df.Date.where(df.Date.dt.weekday == 0, df.Date - Week(weekday=0))
0   2018-07-30
1   2018-08-20
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

The trick being that you need to not do the subtraction where the weekday is already Monday (weekday == 0).  This says, "in cases where weekday is already zero, do nothing; else, return Monday of that week."

Answer (score 2):

#### `pandas` version

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Item': ['A', 'B'],
    'Date': ['2018-08-03', '2018-08-20']
})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date) #Use pd.Timestamp
df.Date - pd.TimedeltaIndex(df.Date.dt.dayofweek,unit='d')
```

Output:

```
0   2018-07-30
1   2018-08-20
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Docs on used functions: [pd.TimedeltaIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.TimedeltaIndex.html), [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html)

Working with date and time: [Time Series / Date functionality](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to jpp answer using only pandas:

```
df_plot['first_date'] = df_plot['date'] - pd.to_timedelta(df_plot['date'].dt.weekday, unit='days')
```